# <input type="number"> works in .html files and does not work in .php files

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I am new to PHP and I have found that simple input in form with number type works differently in .html and .php files.

the code:

.php file:

```
 <form>
    <input type="number" name="num1" placeholder = "Number 1">
    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder = "Number 2">
    <select name="operator" id="opr1">
        <option>Add</option>
        <option>Subtract</option>
        <option>Multiply</option>
        <option>Devide</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button name="submit" value = "submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

.html file:

```
<form action="contactform.php" method="GET">
    <label for=""></label>
    <input type="number" name="number1" step="0.0001" placeholder="number1">

    Male:<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" checked>
    Female:<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">
    Other:<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other">
    <input type="password" name="pwd" value="">
    <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="write a message"></textarea>
    <select name="carSelect" id="">
        <option value="ford">Ford</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>


</form>
```

results... 
php (strange symbols instead of numbers):
[image]

.html everything is ok:
[image]

Thanks everyone for answers in advance.

Comment: "I am new to PHP and I have found that simple input in form with number type works differently in .html and .php files." — It doesn't. HTML generated from PHP is not different to HTML generated from a static file. I can't reproduce the problem you have. Neither version of HTML you provide puts a default value in the field. Either version allows me to type any character I like.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: This is not reproducible with the code you have shown. Your “PHP file” does not even contain any PHP code, just HTML, which will be passed on to the browser unchanged. The only thing that I can possibly see coming into play here, is character encoding. PHP, if not instructed otherwise, will return a Content-Type header including the charset that was specified via the `default_charset` config setting. The default value for that is `UTF-8`, so if you _saved_ your file in a different character encoding, that would clash here.

Comment: HTML doesn't have memory, the browser doesn't know or care how it was generated. You seem to have many other differences (http vs file, different HTML and possibly other settings). I can't search the symbol in Google because it's a picture and I can't speak Arabic but it visually resembles number 4 in Arabic. If that's the case (I'm not saying it is) then "not working" is not a really accurate description. **Edit:** it's Devanagari, see Niet's answer.

Comment: @CBroe Yes I understand that this is just HTML which will be passed to browser unchanged. Then I don't understand why it do work with original HTML file and does not work when it is passed from PHP file from the same XAMP server.
Any help would be great on this. 
I put <meta charset="UTF-8"> in both headers. And I am not located in Arabic countries.

Comment: For starters, you should test your HTML version via a web server as well - right now, you are only opening it directly via the local file system, so that might cause different “conditions” already. _“I put <meta charset="UTF-8"> in both headers”_ - that has lower priority, then a charset specified via the Content-Type response header. Check the config setting I mentioned, maybe your PHP is for some reason configured to indicate a different one by default.

Comment: @CBroe Actually I opened both via XAMP. The "lang" attribute helped. Here is a code: "<input lang = "en" type="number" step = "0.001" name="num1" placeholder = "Number 1">"

Comment: _“Actually I opened both via XAMP”_ - not according to your screenshots. `file:///D:/…` is not going via any web server, that is access directly via the local file system.

Comment: @CBroe Well as for the screenshots - you are right, but I actually opened both via XAMP and result was the same. Anyway, many thanks for your time and replies:) Cheers:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WHATWG [says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type=number)) (emphasis mine):

> This specification does not define what user interface user agents are
>   to use; **user agent vendors are encouraged to consider what would best
>   serve their users' needs**. For example, a user agent in Persian or
>   Arabic markets might support Persian and Arabic numeric input
>   (converting it to the format required for submission as described
>   above). Similarly, a user agent designed for Romans might display the
>   value in Roman numerals rather than in decimal; or (more
>   realistically) a user agent designed for the French market might
>   display the value with apostrophes between thousands and commas before
>   the decimals, and allow the user to enter a value in that manner,
>   internally converting it to the submission format described above.

Some quick testing suggest that the national format used to display numbers in `<input type="number">` controls is indeed browser dependant:

- Firefox considers the HTML language (`lang` attribute)
- Chrome considers browser language (`Accept-Language` string?)

```html
<div lang="en"><input type="number" value="1234567.890"></div>
<div lang="es"><input type="number" value="1234567.890"></div>
<div lang="ar"><input type="number" value="1234567.890"></div>
<div lang="hi"><input type="number" value="1234567.890"></div>
```

The above snippet looks like this in my computer:

[image: Screenshot of input elements in different languages]

I don't really know how to trigger Devanagari script (`hi` was just a guess).

Comment: it works even without div tag. Here: "<input lang = "en" type="number" step = "0.001" name="num1" placeholder = "Number 1">"

Comment: @IvanSavchenco Correct. I wanted to highlight that language settings are inherited as expected, they aren't something you need to set for every element in page.

Answer (score 1):

That is a 6 in the [Devanagari script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari#Numerals).

`<input type="number" />` - along with `date` and other HTML5 form input types - are locale-aware and will adjust their appearance to the user's browser. Sometimes, this is done based on the headers sent by the server.

There's nothing special about PHP, but in this case it seems there's configuration differences between your PHP server and just loading a plain HTML file.

Comment: I am not located in Arabic countries. And I put <meta charset="UTF-8"> in header.

Comment: @IvanSavchenco UTF-8 is just an encoding. It doesn't imply any language or culture per se.

Answer (score 0):

input type number takes all special symbols along with letter 'e', to prevent this problem, call a javascript function on onkeypress.

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
    return true;
}
```

And Call it as

onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"